# Kubernetes Ingress Host Configuration Automation

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, hostname

I have a k8s cluster that I run. I have the necessary scripts that can create the cluster and destroy it as necessary. I have some of my applications running on this cluster. Recently I configured Ingress controller service and I'm routing my traffic to the application services via this Ingress controller.

I would like to access the application using a hostname where I have defined this in my Ingress rules. For example., when I need to access application A, which has a service IP like 192.168.0.100, I would use the hostname application.a.local. For this I need to edit the /etc/hosts file on the machine that is running the cluster and add an entry there. This is a manual approach. How could I automate this?

Is there a better approach to configure hostname mapping? Any suggestions?

Comment: I run a local dns server (unbound) that will return a locally configured domain first, or forward the request out to normal dns if not. For the automation side, maybe try it with [powerdns](https://www.powerdns.com/) instead as it provides a [management API](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/http-api/zone.html)

Comment: Alternatively use a real domain and host it on any of the cloud providers DNS, they provide the same management API's and might cost about $15 per year total.

Comment: This is fine, but what happens when I destroy the cluster and recreate it? The IP address of the cluster is ephimeral so the next time I create a new cluster I have to do this configuration manually again. So can I automate this somehow?

Comment: Something like this would work? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/

Comment: There is also a GitHub issue filed for this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43632

Comment: Yep, that will do if all you need is the name inside certain pods. I was thinking more outside.

Comment: I was unsure about that concept if it would work for external facing hostnames, but what I certainly need is hostname and ip mapping for external access. Is there a better way to do this without the need to manually edit the hosts file?

Comment: You could use a shell script to get your service ips and put in the `/etc/hosts`, and use cronjob to run it in a interval of time you want. If you are using a cloud provider, you could use a internal domain, like CloudDNS (gcp) or Route53(AWS). Is this your case?

Comment: This is what I ended up with at last! It is to some extent automated and enough for me for now!